# How can i pause executing code until animation finishes

Tags: java, android

public void startGameButtonClicked(View view) {
        final TextView shadow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_menu_start_game_button_shadow);

```
    final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.main_menu);
    shadow.startAnimation(animation);

    /** Ugly prototype pausing */
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < 600) {
        Log.i("test", Boolean.toString(animation.hasEnded()));
    }


    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_BUTTON_ID, START_GAME_BUTTON);

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();
}
```

My animation has duration = 400, how can i pause everything except animation after calling shadow.startAnimation(animation); ?
I asking becouse, as you can see - animation is set for button click action, which kills current activity, so animation isnt shown completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define "pause everything" to get an answer for it.

What I'll propose is to implement [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) in your Activity, and point it to the Animation. Then in onAnimationEnd() simply call finish().